# How to make for /f deal with space in the file path?

Tags: windows, command-line, path

The command `for /f %%f in (c:\path\list.txt) do echo %%f` gets confused if `path` contains spaces.

Typically, I'd just put quotes around the path (`in ("c:\path with spaces\list.txt") do`), but in this case, `for` incorrectly believes the path to be the content to work on instead.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq" in ("c:\path with spaces\list.txt") do
```

With this option, `"path"` will work for quoting file paths, and `` `cmd` `` will capture a command's output.